# Outlook Add-In does not show up on Outlook for Mobile app (iOS or Android)

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am the developer of an Outlook Add-In that has been live for some time and available to our users via the Outlook desktop and web applications. We have recently attempted to make our add-in available on Outlook for Mobile as well, but the live version of the add-in on the add-in store simply will not show up for us (during internal testing) or for our users.

- We have added the MobileFormFactor section to the manifest
- When we install our internal test versions of our add-in manifest, we can see these internal versions of our add-in become available in the Outlook iOS and Android apps
- Our add-in submission has been accepted in Microsoft Partner Center
- We have checked the box in Microsoft Partner Center for "Make my product available on iOS and Android (if applicable)." and have connected our Apple ID
- The "Packages" page in Microsoft Partner Center indicates that our add-in will be available on Outlook on Android and Outlook on iOS
- If we take our production manifest and modify the Id, and sideload it, we can see the add-in in our Outlook Android and iOS apps

Despite all of the above, our production Outlook add-in which is available in the Add-in store does not show up in the Outlook mobile app on either Android or iOS.

What else am I missing here that will enable our users to use our add-in on the Outlook mobile Android/iOS apps?